# C++ Windows Shell Extensions - Win7 32bit - 64bit compatibility issues

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-7, visual-studio-2005, shell-extensions

i have visual studio 2005 and i am writing a shell extension for windows explorer.

It works in Windows Vista 32bit where i compile the project.
It also works on Windows 7 64bit when the project has been compiled on Windows7 64bit.

Now i want to test it also on Windows 7 32bit when the project has been compiled on Windows Vista 32bit but it does not work !

Are there compatibility issues between c++ versions ?

The shell extension dll won't register. (side by side error).

Is it necessary to compile it on Windows 7 32bit to make it work ?

My dll is based on the example of "complete idiot's guide to writing shell extensions" on codeproject.com

Thanks !

Comment: Did you get the manifest right? Does the 32 bit machine have the 2005 C runtime?

Answer (score 0):

it should not be compiled in debug mode but only in release mode.

also in a frequent example on the internet there is a bug and the int should get
converted to IntPtr...